# how can i bookmark songs in my django project with rest framework and js

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, fetch

I've been trying to put the favorites feature for days with django rest framework and javascript api fetch in my lyrics project but without success all the methods I'm trying don't work please help me I'm a beginner in javascript, even in api with django too.

here is what I tried, where did I mow

apiviews.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status,permissions
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.viewsets import ReadOnlyModelViewSet
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.response import Response


from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from .serializers import SongSerializer


from .models import Song, User
from .models import Song, Favorite


class FavoritesongView(APIView):
    serializer_class = SongSerializer
    queryset = Song.objects.all()

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def favorite(self, request, id):
        song = self.get_object()
        user = request.user

        if user not in song.favorited_by.all():
            song.favorited_by.add(user)
            song.save()

        return Response({'status': 'favorited'})

    @favorite.mapping.delete
    def unfavorite(self, request, id=None):
        song = self.get_object()
        user = request.user

        if user in song.favorited_by.all():
            song.favorited_by.remove(user)
            song.save()

        return Response({'status': 'unfavorited'})
```

api_urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from favorites.apiViews import FavoritesongView



urlpatterns = [
        path('songs/<int:id>/favorite/', FavoritesongView.as_view())
]
```

Js file

```
function addToFavorites(songId) {
  fetch(`/api/songs/${songId}/favorite/`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

function removeFromFavorites(songId) {
  fetch(`/api/songs/${songId}/favorite/`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from favorites.apiViews import FavoritesongView



urlpatterns = [
        path('songs/<int:id>/favorite/', FavoritesongView.as_view())
]
```

html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/images/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/favoriteApi.js">
   
    <title>Lys de Vallée</title>
</head>
{% include 'SearchHeader.html' %}
<body>
    <h1>Liste de chansons</h1>
<ul>
    {% for song in songs %}
   <li> <a href="{% url 'lyrics' song.id %}">{{ song.title }}</a></li>
   <li>{% for song in songs %}
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if song.is_favorite %}
      <button onclick="removeFromFavorites({{ song.id }})">ajouter aux favoris</button>
    {% else %}
      <button onclick="addToFavorites({{ song.id }})">enlever aux favoris</button>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
 </li>
  
  

    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
```

indeed the button that I put in html does not send any request and no song is added to the favorites but nevertheless I did as I had seen in the explanation

I tried many methods, without finding solutions for days

Comment: You're loading your JS file via the `<link />` tag which is intended for css files. You should be loading it using the `<script />` tag instead.

Comment: I put this: <script src="/static/js/favoriteApi.js/"></script> but it creates the error I click in the button to add to favorites: TypeError: FavoritesongView.post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'song_id'
[15/Jun/2023 17:16:05] "POST /api/songs/2/favorite/HTTP/1.1" 500 91978